# Popovers and bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to show a popover when ever the user is hovering over some li's in my page. So after checking the example in bootstrap page This is what I did. The script is placed before closing body tag

```
$("li").each(function (i){
    $(this).popover({title:"Title", content:"Content", trigger:"hover"});
});
```

But still the popover won't show.

my html is simple

```
<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   etc...
</ul>
```

No popover showing up though...What am i doing wrong?

Comment: any errors in your browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the script

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("li").popover({
        title: "Title",
        content: "Content",
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: 'bottom'
    }); //<-- missing  } here
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gZrLb/)

Comment: It was ok on my code, just got it wrong typing it here. Thanks. Why isn't this working then http://bootply.com/94050

Comment: @Apostolos it is the problem is placement, add the placement option as shown above it will be fine. By default the popover is displayed at the extreme right

Comment: placement bottom works, but no other placements("right" e.g). Why is that?

Comment: @Apostolos if you give a width to the `ul` then right also works http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gZrLb/2/

Comment: Thanks!! Now how could i have guessed that....:(.Web technologies sometimes feel confusing..

Answer (score 0):

I would put the title and he content into he DOM instead of in the jQuery script (Separation of Concerns). This means using the HTML 5 `data-` attributes within each li tag. E.g

```
<li data-title="The Title" data-content="The content">One</li>
```

This means that you do not have to specify the title and content of the popover within the jQuery script.

Comment: I want to use the popup to render html eventualy and not just a string.